# Cryptic error from request that had been working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I wanted to know if there were any changes to the dlp api in regards to authentication or whether the service may be down. Seems like the docs don't mention any changes.

The request is formated as such

```
POST https://dlp.googleapis.com/v2/projects/<project_id>/content:deidentify?key=<key> HTTP/1.1

{
    "item": {
        "value": "[\"Humphrey\",\"Roy\",\"Hodge\",\"Juarez\",\"Watkins\",\"Calderon\",\"Mayer\",\"Drake\",\"Valdez\",\"Landry\"]"
    },
    "deidentifyConfig": {
        "infoTypeTransformations": {
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "primitiveTransformation": {
                        "replaceWithInfoTypeConfig": {}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "inspectConfig": {
        "infoTypes": [
            {
                "name": "US_SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER"
            },
            {
                "name": "CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER"
            },
            {
                "name": "US_DRIVERS_LICENSE_NUMBER"
            },
            {
                "name": "EMAIL_ADDRESS"
            },
            {
                "name": "PERSON_NAME"
            },
            {
                "name": "PHONE_NUMBER"
            },
            {
                "name": "LOCATION"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The error returned is very cryptic and thus I'm having a hard time figuring out what exactly is going on especially given that the exact same request had been working earlier.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a bug, the engineering team has a patch for it and is in the process of rolling out the fix. (it only impacts calls unauthenticated, so calling with auth is the work around)

Comment: Thanks @jordanna-chord. How do we get notified of bugs like this in the future? Is there a better medium than stack overflow that I overlooked?

Comment: This is fine, we monitor this alias for issues. We had already noticed this issue and were rolling out a fix, and at the moment don't have other channels of communication setup beyond what's offered at https://cloud.google.com/support/.